# Git (1.8.1.2) error when adding interactively

Tags: linux, perl, git

Attempting a `git add -i` resulted in the following error:

```
Can't locate Error.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/share/perl/5.14.2
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.14
/usr/share/perl/5.14
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
.) at /usr/share/perl5/Git.pm line 101.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Git.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive line 7.
```

I had no issues at all adding files manually or during any other git operation, either perl wasn't finding the right version of `Error.pm` or it didn't come with my git package.

I haven't tried to do an interactive add in quite some time so I couldn't say when this started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this by executing the following (used cpanm, however cpan would work as well): `cpanm Error.pm`

Comment: @uDaY I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer, apparently.

Comment: @cerberos Yes, whether with `cpan` or `cpanm`, as long as you get Error.pm installed it should work again. :-)

Comment: @SW I see, thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer didn't work in my situation, however this command did:

`sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Error'`

From [here](http://tamsler.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/git-svn-info-cant-locate-errorpm-on-mac.html). Running on `CentOS release 5.9 (Final)`

Comment: cpnanm failed with "Module::Build version 0.39 required--this is only version 0.38 at ./Build line 43.
-> FAIL Installing Error failed. See ~/.cpanm/build.log for details.". This one worked just fine.

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in substitution (s///) at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/File/Basename.pm line 341.` having another great day~

Comment: On CentOS you need to install the (missing) dependency `perl-Error` (ie: `yum install -y perl-Error` and your `git add -p` will work).

Comment: @bufh Can you add that as a separate answer, so we can upvote it in favor of the others that did not work? :)